# Weird characters in form input populated by jQuery

Tags: jquery, tinymce, shortcode

I'm working in a tinymce button to insert shortcodes. It's based in a list of shortcodes, and each one opens a popup window with that shortcode options, from a js structure.

In a very simplified version, the code is:

```
(function() {   
     tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.sympleShortcodeMce', {
       init : function(ed, url){
       //do nothing
        },
        createControl : function(btn, e) {
            if ( btn == "symple_shortcodes_button" ) {
                var a = this;
                var btn = e.createSplitButton('symple_button', {
title: "Insert Shortcodes",
image: "shortcode-button.png",
icons: false,
                });
                btn.onRenderMenu.add(function (c, b) {
        a.render( b, "Caixa", "caixa" );
                });

              return btn;
            }
            return null;               
        },
        render : function(ed, title, id) {
            ed.add({
                title: title,
                onclick: function () {


// Box
if(id == "caixa") {
H = jQuery(window).height()* 0.9,
W = ( 720 < width ) ? 720 : width;
W = W - 120;
H = H - 84;
tb_show( 'Insert Box - Shortcode', '#TB_inline?width=' + W + '&height=' + H + '&inlineId=mycaixa-form' );
}

return false;
                }
            })
        }

    });
tinymce.PluginManager.add("symple_shortcodes", tinymce.plugins.sympleShortcodeMce);

// BOXES
jQuery(function(){
var formcaixa = jQuery('<div id="mycaixa-form"><table id="mycaixa-table" class="form-table">\
<tr>\
<th><label for="mycaixa-icone">Ícone</label></th>\
<td>\
<div class="nochecked"><input type="radio" name="icone" value="meh"><i class="icon-meh"></i></div>\
<div class="nochecked"><input type="radio" name="icone" value="smile"><i class="icon-smile"></i></div>\
<br />\
<small>Box icon</small></td>\
</tr><br />\
</table>\
<p class="submit">\
<input type="button" id="mycaixa-submit" class="button-primary" value="Create Box" name="submit" />\
</p>\
</div>');

var tablecaixa = formcaixa.find('table');
formcaixa.appendTo('body').hide();

jQuery('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
vals = jQuery('input[type="radio"]:checked').map(function() {
return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(vals);
jQuery('#mycaixa-icone').val(vals);
}).change();

// handles the click event of the submit button
formcaixa.find('#mycaixa-submit').click(function(){
// defines the options and their default values
var options = {
'icone' : ''
};

if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent() == "") {
contentcaixa = "INSIRA CONTEÚDO"; }
else {contentcaixa = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();}

var shortcodecaixa = '[caixa';
for(var index in options) {
var value = tablecaixa.find('#mycaixa-' + index).val();         
// attaches the attribute to the shortcode only if it's different from the default value
if ( value !== options[index] ) {
shortcodecaixa += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
} }
shortcodecaixa += ']'+contentcaixa+'[/caixa]';

// inserts the shortcode into the active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcodecaixa);
// closes Thickbox
tb_remove(); }) })

/* END FORMS */ 
})();
```

So, what i'm trying to do is use the value from checkboxes to set value of a input text. This value is taken in `var value = tablecaixa.find('#mycaixa-' + index).val();` and used to create the shortcode.

But when i change the checkboxes, the value of input text changes, but there's a "2,public" inserted along with the value. So, instead of have the value "smile", or "meh", i get "2,public,smile" or "2,public,meh".

Any idea what is this?

Comment: can you show us a live example?

Comment: Sorry, i can't, local server. But i solved. Probably not the best way, but it's working:

`var element= jQuery('#mycaixa-icone').val(vals);
element.val(element.val().replace(/2,public,/ig, ""));`

Comment: you may post this here as an answer and accept it later on